# How to add no follow to specific links?

Tags: php, functions, seo, regex

I have some cloaking affiliate links to which I would like to add the attributes of **nofollow**.

However, I'm looking for a way in coding that will allow me to target links that contain specific string, like **/go/brand**.

While searching, I found this code somewhere, but it didn't work for me in functions.php, so I was hoping someone might provide me with something that may do the job for me.

Thank you so much in advance!

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_string_replacements');
function my_string_replacements ( $content ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_main_query() ) {
        return preg_replace('/<a(.*href=".*\/go\/pluto\/?".*)>/', '<a$1 rel="nofollow">', $content );
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replace code is replacing the whole a element content with `<a rel="nofollow">`. Here's the correction:

I used `(.+?)` between `<a and href"` and before and after `/go/pluto/` to the closing `>`. Then in the replace, we put `$1 $2 $3` etc. to keep them and add `rel="nofollow"`. You can check in this [test](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/us3), and here's explanation about the [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2888442/12455951).

```
return preg_replace('/<a(.+?)href="(.+?)\/go\/pluto\/(.+?)"(.+?)>/', '<a$1href="$2/go/pluto/$3" rel="nofollow"$4>', $content );
```

**Edit:**

Considering there are links that contains rel attribute already, we will run regex that searches for links that does have rel but doesn't contain nofollow and add nofollow:

```
return preg_replace('/<a(.+?)href="(.+?)\/go\/pluto\/(.+?)"(.+?)rel="((?!nofollow).)*(?=")/', '$0 nofollow', $content);
```

I'm still figuring out the appropriate code to insert rel if the a element doesn't contain it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, it partially worked, it added the nofollow for some links and for some others it didnt. The link that it didn't work with had already some attributes like rel="noopener noreferrer"

Comment: I updated the answer with regex code to add nofollow to existing rel

Comment: Thank you so much mate, you saved me :) I appreciate your followup mate, the following one worked for me and this has done the job for me: return preg_replace('/<a(.+?)href="(.+?)\/go\/(.+?)"(.+?)>/', '<a$1href="$2/go/$3" rel="nofollow"$4>', $content );

Comment: You are welcome anytime buddy :) please approve and vote up the answer.